# Words describing an event that has an unspecified time or place

Tags: single-word-requests, science

Looking for a single word derived form word like 'temporal', that would described event that has unspecified time of occurrence.

First thought was 'temporamental', but looks like it's not an actual word.
The analogue word for a spatially undefined event that reads similarly should also exist.

I've read this in a scientific paper but can't recollect where.

Comment: Hi Fyga, do you actually mean 'time' or rather the 'duration' of an event?

Comment: "Atemporal" means independent of time. Not exactly what you asked for, so not an answer but maybe close enough to be helpful.

Comment: Can you provide more context, details, why the time/location is unspecified, what kind of range? A term from physics for an event at an arbitrary point in spacetime is very different to a word for a meeting where the time or venue haven't been agreed. Even within science, terminology in physics and paleontology is very different.

Comment: This may be jargon from a particular branch of science. Do you recall the branch, or have your tried cross-posting to a science board?

Comment: Can you give examples of how you would use this word in sentences?

Comment: Random? . . . .

Comment: 'Unlocated' has the prototypical sense 'not located spatially', but would not be used for 'venue yet to be decided'. 'Non-locate' is rare.

Comment: Do you actually mean 'happening at an unpredictable time'? (In which case 'extemporaneous', which carries this (as a non-default) sense is a possibility.) // 'Diachronic' carries the sense 'occurring over time rather than at a specified point in time'.

Answer (score 1):

This may not suit your particular use case, but if you have an *approximate* sense of when a historical event happened, but it is very inexact, you could use the preposition **circa,** defined [by Merriam-Webster as:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/circa)

> at approximately, in approximately, or of approximately—used especially with dates

An example would be: "he died circa 300 BC."

Comment: Approximate is not the same as unspecified.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for a word like **"ephemeral"** which means short-lived, or temporary.

As for a similar word with respect to a "spatial" application, perhaps the word **"peripheral"** would be what you had in mind--which means something is taking place in the margins or edges of a place, and/or is of minor importance.

Answer (score 0):

**Diachronic** carries the sense 'occurring over time rather than at a specified point in time':

> *diachronic* ... Occurring over or changing with time.

[[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/diachronic#English)]

It derives from the Greek rather than the Latin.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diachrony_and_synchrony#:%7E:text=Synchrony%20and%20diachrony%20are%20two,taking%20its%20history%20into%20account.) has (bolding mine):

> Synchrony and diachrony are two complementary viewpoints in linguistic
> analysis. A synchronic approach (from Ancient Greek: συν- "together"
> and χρόνος "time") considers a language at a moment in time without
> taking its history into account. Synchronic linguistics aims at
> describing a language **at a specific point of time**, often the
> present. In contrast, a diachronic (from δια- "through" and χρόνος
> "time") approach, as in historical linguistics, considers the
> development and evolution of a language through history.